# Unable to transfer data from text file to list collection (and class?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list

Could someone pls help me out. I have gone through every line, but just can't figure out what I have missed. No error but when I run it, somehow the list is not populated at all. Only have this line "Project.ContactDetails" repeated as many times as the total no of lines in the textfile, which I think it means the list is populated with "" for each line of data in the text file, instead of the data itself (instead of Mary, Jane, John, the list got "", "", ""). I have looked at other similar cases including the MSDN examples, technically copied their code, but still nothing in the list.

Or if there are links you can suggest for me to read so I can understand list and class better, that would be awesome. I have read many, but they all mostly are fairly simple like, the list consists of names only (Mary, Jane, John), not something like this (John Farmer, 25 Pitt Street, 99887766; Mary Jane, 26 Argyle Road, 97776652).

*Pulling my hair -  Out to buy a wig - Will be back.

```
public partial class frmContact : Form
{
    //declare file, class and list
    string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Contacts.txt";
    List<ContactDetails> CList = new List<ContactDetails>()

    public frmContact()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //-------------------//
    // LOAD CONTACT FORM //
    //-------------------//
    private void frmContact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //create Contacts.txt if it does not exist
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Create(fileName).Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New " + fileName +"  Has Been Created");
        }
        //if file already exists
        else
        {
            StreamReader readOb = new StreamReader(fileName);
            using (readOb)
            {
                while (!readOb.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string rdLine = readOb.ReadLine(); //read data in file by line
                    string[] tmpArr = rdLine.Split(',');
                    lbContact.Items.Add(tmpArr[0]+","+tmpArr[1]);
                    CList.Add(new ContactDetails() { Last = tmpArr[0], First = tmpArr[1] });
                }
            }
            //check if list populated
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (ContactDetails item in CList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item+counter.ToString());
                counter++;
            }

        }
        tbLast.Select(); // set cursor to Surname textbox
    }
}

class ContactDetails
{
    public string Last {get; set;}
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Addr { get; set; }
    public string Sub { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mob { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Something to do with `listBox1.Items.Add(item+counter.ToString());`, what does item+counter suppose to do? just remove the + counter and retry..

Comment: Short answer: Debug. Add a breakpoint and follow the code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel how do you do that?

Comment: [Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) and [Debugging small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Can you please re-title this question so it explains the problem rather than simply asking for help. SO has a LOT of people asking for help - a good title will attract the people who can help you

Comment: You need to debug this, personally I'd put a breakpoint on the foreach line and see what's in CList - is it populated? If so are the elements added to listBox1 if not why not? Move your breakpoint higher up - is it loading the file ok?

Comment: I know they are in the array, because I can see them listed in  lbcontact. I put another one , listbox1, just to see if the data also in the list collection. Result: nope. I know they arent in the list collection, cause even when I use messagebox to show the content of the collection, the result still empty

Comment: your problem is most likely the  listBox1.Items.Add(item+counter.ToString()); You are adding a object and also doing counter.ToString(). If I am correct this will most likely call the ToString on your ContactDetails class. If you want to this behavior override the ToStringMethod in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the loop that populates the list.

```
foreach (ContactDetails item in CList)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item+counter.ToString());
    counter++;
}
```

The result of `item.ToString()`, which is called implicitly here, is the name of the class (in this case `Project.ContactDetails`).

You could override the `.ToString()` method in your entity class (Project.ContactDetails) to return the correct text, or you could add `item.First` to the list, which would add the first name.

```
foreach (ContactDetails item in CList)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item.First + counter++);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, item.First would be referring to the list collection or the class? I thought list would be referred to as something like cList[0]?
I saw the override .ToString() in the example, I guess now I know what it's for now. Thank you.

Comment: item.First would refer to the First property of the current item in the list, so for each item it should display different text.